# trying to load next content form xml Jquery it loads but its below the prevs. how can i remove default xml content and put the next one in

Tags: jquery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>

<poster>
      <title>Ol&apos; 55</title>

      <info>Tom Waits</info>

      <rating>tomwaits_ol55</rating>

      <img>post-img/DSC1.jpg</img>
</poster>

<poster>
      <title>King Contrary Man</title>

      <info>The Cult</info>

      <rating>tomwaits_ol55</rating>

      <img>post-img/DSC2.jpg</img>
</poster>

<poster>
      <title>Drunken Chorus</title>

      <info>The Trashcan Sinatras</info>

      <rating>trashcansinatras_drunkenchorus</rating>

      <img>post-img/DSC3.jpg</img>
</poster>


 </response>

/*-------------------------------------------*/

$(document).ready(function(){

              var i = 0;  


 $.ajax({type: "get",url: "test.xml",dataType: "xml",success: manipulateXml});

           function manipulateXml(data){

 $(data).find("poster:eq("+i+")").each(function(){

              var title = $(this).find("title").text();

              var info = $(this).find("info").text();

              var rating = $(this).find("rating").text();

              var image = $(this).find("img").text();

              var output = title;

              var infofield = info;

              var ratfield = rating;

              var images = '<img src="' + image + '"/>';

            $("#all_Txp1").append(output);

            $(".all_inBox1").append(infofield);

            $(".all_raBox1").append(ratfield); 

            $("#all_myPicture1").append(images);                

            $(".all_sefield1").slideUp(); 

 $('.all_seIma1').click(function($e){

    $e.preventDefault();

 $('.all_sefield1').slideToggle();

          });  

 $('.all_back1').bind('click',function($e){

    $e.preventDefault();

    i--;
    manipulateXml(data);



  });

 $('.all_forward1').bind('click',function($e){

    $e.preventDefault();

    i++;

    manipulateXml(data);    


  });
```

Comment: Please, please, please please please learn how StackOverflow likes to have questions formatted and clearly written. Put your question in the body, post the MINIMUM code necessary to reproduce your problem, and make sure it's formatted correctly. (Welcome to our site!)

Answer (score 0):

your code do a link prev next also into xml. My xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Poemes>
    <Object>
      <Category>Amore</Category>
      <Title>Rose simmetrie</Title>
      <Date>12/11/2011</Date>
      <Description>Eterno paradiso incontaminato di orchidee Distesa tropicale di spiagge bagnate dal sole Dolce lato dell'animo umano Scultura di bellezza e perfezione Croce e delizia Candido orsacchiotto simbolo di tenerezza e di pace Viso del neonato con i suoi occhi che ti guarda Primo bacio mai scordato Realizzare una tua passione Amore che non muori</Description>
      <Tag> Amore, Rose simmetrie, Emozioni, Femminile, Beltà, Volontà, Meraviglia, Mondo antico, Versi, Testo, Parole, Metafora, Dedica</Tag>
    </Object>

    <Object>
      <Category>Amore</Category>
      <Title>Pure emozioni</Title>
      <Date>14/11/2011</Date>
      <Description>Eterno paradiso incontaminato di orchidee Distesa tropicale   di      spiagge bagnate dal sole Dolce lato dell'animo umano Scultura di bellezza e   perfezione        Croce e delizia Candido orsacchiotto simbolo di tenerezza e di pace      Viso del neonato con i suoi occhi che ti guarda Primo bacio mai scordato         Realizzare una tua passione Amore che non muori         </Description>
      <Tag> Amore, Pure, Emozioni, Paradiso, Scultura, Viso nenonato, Passione, Versi,      Testo, Parole, Astratto, Sentimento universale</Tag>
    </Object>
 </Poemes>
```

I created two `button` for next and prev for scroll page on the xml.
The `id` button called `#SlideXml-left` (prec) `#SlideXml-right` (next). What write for created slide of my xml.